# git status no muestra modified

Tags: javascript, git

estoy empezando un curso de programación y en el visual code se supone que cuando hago algún cambio sale una M y que cuando pongo git status tiene que salir en rojo modified y el nombre pero solo me sale nothing to commit

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La ruta de los archivos parce ser diferente, según veo es algo como `...02-JS-I/homework/` y tu estás haciendo el git status sobre alguna carpeta llamada OneDrive.

Comment: Se ve el cambio en el archivo, pero no lo has guardado, es decir, `git` no sabe que has hecho cambio, ya que aún no has salvado el cambio.

Comment: Por otro lado, te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Evita usar imágenes para mostrar tu código. En este caso en particular la imagen me ha permitido ver que no has guardado los cambios, pero de todas formas, es una de las primeras preguntas de aclaración que te hubieran realizado aunque no subieras imagen alguna. Saludos

Comment: Mauricio Contreras
 efectivamente, estaba omitiendo el ctrl s. Gracias